# Change back to default exception page

Tags: laravel

For some reason, my project has switched to an exception page similar to this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGVKQ.png

All my other projects, even a new one I made 3 days ago, has the normal Laravel exception page where it breaks down everything extremely nicely, which looks like this:

https://freek.dev/uploads/media/ignition-2022/ignition.png

What happened? I can't figure out what I did to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, somehow I accidentally removed this from the composer.json file...

```
"spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
```

under `require-dev` for anyone curious